# Looking for deep water series

Tags: story-identification

I read a book about space travel and stuff.
So these people have the genes of earth and want to take it onto a different planet that is not polluted like crazy. The main character (Red, I think) keeps having hallucinations of his pre-clone life.
I've read the first and second but it says trilogy.

Does the third book exist? 
Where can I find it?

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Maybe a title from one of the books? The plot you describe is a very common sci-fi theme.

Comment: Let me add a few questions. What does "deep water" mean? Do the characters live underwater for much of the story? If so, do they have gills? Is everybody on the new planet a clone of someone back on Earth, or is it unusual for "Red" to be a clone? Do the humans have "Faster than Light" (FTL) space travel, or does it take years for a colony ship from Earth to reach another solar system because it moves slower than light? When did you first read the book? (For instance, if it was back in the 1990s, then we could ignore anything first published in the 21st Century.)

Comment: Hello John, and welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack. Just to be clear, are you looking for the series in general and for the third book specifically, or do you _know_ what the series is and are you looking for _just_ the third book?

Answer (score 5):

I take it you mean the [Deepwater trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepwater_trilogy), consisting of the books Deepwater Black, Deepwater Landing and Deepwater Angels (which should be the one you are looking for).

> How would you react if you were only thirteen or fourteen years old and one day you discovered your entire life that you had been living thus far is only a dream, or a pre-existing hallucination which is a memory from a person who had once been you? A person whom you had been cloned from, whose life you had been living until now.

Comment: I was wondering why he used the words "deep water" in the title of the post. I knew that might be a quote from the source material, with a special meaning, but it didn't come across clearly that this was his recollection of the title of the series (and/or part of the titles of individual volumes).